# Rendering Layout for specific actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, view

Here I've  a controller with 4 actions and i wanna apply application layout ( the default layout ) to new action only , or in other words i wanna except only index action from the layout so i write this but it doesn't work, the index template is rendering with the layout.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    layout 'application', :except => :index

    def index
    end 

    def new
    end


    def create
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end

end
```

also I tried

```
layout 'application', :only => :new
```

but it doesn't work too, same problem which the index template is rendering with layout.
any suggestions what's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method to define your layout and fix your layout only on new action

```
layout :my_layout

def my_layout
  params[:action] == 'new' ? 'application' : nil
end
```

Comment: Well, it works!! but do you have any idea why layout 'application', :except => :index doesn't work?? 
btw this way
layout 'false', :except => :new 
works too

Comment: i think it's because in my case I fix layout to nil in all case instead of new action. But with using :except or :only, it's the inherited layout used in other case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that you can use in your controllers:

```
layout :resolve_layout
...
...

private

def resolve_layout
  if %w(index show).include?(action_name)
    "application"
  elsif %w(show).include?(action_name)
    "admin"
  else
    "generic"
end
```

Basically, treat those arrays as your :only statements for layout that you are giving them if they are evaluated as true when compared with current action_name.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this allows :only, :except, etc.